# Given an array of strings. Print an array of the first two characters of each string

Tags: ruby

a = ["dog","horse","transform","take"]

a = ["do","ho","tr","ta"] так должно быть.

Comment: What have you tried so far and where did you got stuck? Do you know how to transform arrays in general? Do you know how to transform a single string, e.g. `"take"` into `"ta"`? Also, please write in English.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`Array#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Array.html#method-i-map) or `map!` to iterate the array and to return the string prefixes with [`String#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D):

```
a = ["dog", "horse", "transform", "take"]
a.map { |word| word[0, 2] }
#=> ["do", "ho", "tr", "ta"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = %w[dog horse transform take]
```

Code

```
a.map! { |value| value.chars.first(2).join }
p a
```

Output

```
["do", "ho", "tr", "ta"]
```